# CoreData app not syncing with iCloud

Tags: core-data, ios7, xcode6, icloud, magicalrecord

I am running an iPad app on iOS7, XCode 6; I have the device iCloud enabled for Documents and the app enabled for iCloud.  Nothing shows up in iCLoud when I run my app *on the device* and make changes to the Core Data store in the app (using MagicalRecord).

Is there something else I need to do?  (I want to have device sharing and backup capabilities of the Core Data store using MagicalRecord)

**UPDATE:**

Made these changes:

[image]

(I was unable to check "JRSD9A598D" for a container)

and:

[image]

and this is line of code giving me a run-time error:

```
    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithiCloudContainer:@"rolfbucket" localStoreNamed:@"saori.sqlite"];
```

This is the error:

> 2014-11-05 07:53:15.156 SalonBook[223:1607] *** -[NSFileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:]: An error occurred while getting ubiquity container URL: Error Domain=LibrarianErrorDomain Code=11 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LibrarianErrorDomain error 11 - The requested container identifier is not permitted by the client's com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement.)" UserInfo=0x1456bb50 {NSDescription=The requested container identifier is not permitted by the client's com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement.}

I appear to be making progress, but what is causing this error?

Comment: There are a number of things that must be done for Core Data to work with iCloud, including configuring the app ID and the entitlements and using a provisioning profile that includes the correct entitlements. Plus of course using the right options when bringing up the Core Data stack. You need to describe what you've actually done in a lot more detail before you can get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had picked the wrong container; it should have been the one with my bundle ID.  Fixed that and the error went away.